# Spark - Scala : How can I pass more than 10 arguments in a UDF function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, udf

Have a UDF Function where I pass 16 arguments.
But it throws an error stating "`overloaded method udf`"

```
val rec_cutoff = udf(fetch_rec_cutoff(_: String, _: String, _: String, _: String, _: String, 
      _: String, _: String, _: String, _: String, _: String, _: String, _: String, _: String, _: String, _: String, _: String))

  val EC_RECV_CUTOFF_df = EC_END_OF_DAY_df.withColumn("RECV_CUTOFF", rec_cutoff(EC_START_OF_DAY_df.col("STP_FLAG"),
    EC_END_OF_DAY_df.col("TXN_PAYMENT_TYPE"), EC_END_OF_DAY_df.col("COUNTRY_ORIG"),
    EC_END_OF_DAY_df.col("PROC_MODE"), EC_END_OF_DAY_df.col("Receiving_Cut_off"),
    EC_END_OF_DAY_df.col("REMIT_CURRENCY"), EC_END_OF_DAY_df.col("TXN_SOURCE_APPLICATION"),
    EC_END_OF_DAY_df.col("COUNTRY_DEST"), EC_END_OF_DAY_df.col("SUB_PAYMENT_TYPE"),
    EC_END_OF_DAY_df.col("Mon_Cutoff"), EC_END_OF_DAY_df.col("Tue_Cutoff"),
    EC_END_OF_DAY_df.col("Wed_Cutoff"), EC_END_OF_DAY_df.col("Thu_Cutoff"),
    EC_END_OF_DAY_df.col("Fri_Cutoff"), EC_END_OF_DAY_df.col("Sat_Cutoff"),
    EC_END_OF_DAY_df.col("Sun_Cutoff")))

    EC_END_OF_DAY_df.show(1000)

  def fetch_rec_cutoff(stp_flag: String, txn_pymt_type: String, country_orig: String, proc_mode: String, rec_cutoff: String, remit_currency: String, txn_source_app: String, dest_country: String, sub_payment_type: String, mon_cutoff: String, tue_cutoff: String, wed_cutoff: String, thu_cutoff: String, fri_cutoff: String, sat_cutoff: String, sun_cutoff: String): String = {
    " some logics"
}
```

Looked into :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
```

Provision to hold only 10 arguments is available.

Hence I tried to use Tuple and come over this.

```
{
   val udfTuple222 = udf(tupleFn(_: Tuple2[String, String]))

    val xxx = TSCdf.withColumn("newColumnName", udfTuple222(lit(col("Application_System"), col("Transaction_Status"))))

    xxx.show()

  }

  def tupleFn(tuple: Tuple2[String, String]): Int = {

    println("this is : " + tuple._1)
    println("this is tuple 2" + tuple._2)
    1
  }
```

Unfortunately that too throwed an error as below,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.Tuple2 (Application_System,Transaction_Status)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:117)
    at com.scb.cnc.payments.writer.Test$.main(Test.scala:69)
    at com.scb.cnc.payments.writer.Test.main(Test.scala)
```

Kindly assist.